# Python DataFrame - groupby and centroid calculation

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, centroid

I have a dataframe with two columns: one contains a Category and the other contains a 300-dimensional vector. For each of the values in the Category column, I have a lot of 300-dimensional vectors. What I need is to group the dataframe by the Category column and at the same time get the  centroid value of all the vectors that pertain to each Category.

```
Category        Vector   
Balance        [1,2,1,-5,....,9]  
Inquiry        [-5,3,1,5,...,10]  
Card           [-3,1,2,3,...1]  
Balance        [1,3,-2,1,-5,...,7]  
Card           [3,1,3,4,...,2]
```

So in the above case the desired output would be:

```
Category       Vector   
Balance        [1,2.5,-0.5,-2,....,8]  
Inquiry        [-5,3,1,5,...,10]  
Card           [0,1,2.5,3.5,...,1.5]
```

I have already written the following function that gets an array of vectors and calculates its centroid:

```
import numpy as np
    def get_intent_centroid(array):
        centroid = np.zeros(len(array[0]))
        for vector in array:
            centroid = centroid + vector
        return centroid/len(array)
```

so I just need a quick way to apply the function above along with a `groupby` command on the dataframe.

Please excuse my formatting of the dataframes, but I do not know how to format them properly.

Comment: Not sure how to do manipulation of vectors in a column in pandas, but you can try to change these 2 columns to lists, and then do the manipulation and convert back to pandas!

Comment: I think that the whole calculations procedure is going to be much faster if I do not use lists.

Comment: @Tarun How would you approach it using lists?

Comment: I have posted an answer. you can do that if you dont find a way in pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the centroid of a list of vectors is just the mean of each dimension of the vectors, so this can be simplified a great deal to just this.

`df.groupby('Category')['Vector'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.tolist(), axis=0))`

It should be faster than any loop/list conversion method.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP, I have a way to do it through lists :

```
vectorsList = list(df["Vector"])
catList = list(df["Category"])

#create a dict for each category and initialise it with a list of 300, zeros
dictOfCats = {}
for each in set(cat):
    dictOfCats[each]= [0] * 300

#loop through the vectorsList and catList
for i in range(0, len(catList)):
    currentVec = dictOfCats[each]
    for j in range(0, len(vectorsList[i])):
        currentVec[j] = vectorsList[i][j] + currentVec[j]
    dictOfCats[each] = currentVec

#now each element in dict has sum. you can divide it by the count of each category
#you can calculate the frequency by groupby, here since i have used only lists, i am showing execution by lists
catFreq = {} 
for eachCat in catList:
    if(eachCat in catList):
        catList[eachCat] = catList[eachCat] + 1
    else:
        catList[eachCat] = 1


for eachKey in dictOfCats:
    currentVec = dictOfCats[eachKey]
    newCurrentVec = [x / catList[eachKey] for x in currentVec]
    dictOfCats[eachKey] = newCurrentVec

#now change this dictOfCats to dataframe again
```

Please note that there may be bugs in the code since I have not checked it with your data. This will be computationally expensive but should do the work if you are not able to figure out a solution by pandas. If you do come up with a solution in pandas, please post the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'category': 'Balance', 'vector':  [1,2,1,-5,9]},
        {'category': 'Inquiry', 'vector': [-5,3,1,5,10]},
        {'category': 'Card', 'vector': [-3,1,2,3,1]},
        {'category': 'Balance', 'vector':  [1,3,-2,1,7]},
        {'category': 'Card', 'vector':  [3,1,3,4,2]}
    ]
)


def get_intent_centroid(array):
    centroid = np.zeros(len(array[0]))
    for vector in array:
        centroid = centroid + vector
    return centroid/len(array)


df.groupby('category')['vector'].apply(lambda x: get_intent_centroid(x.tolist()))

Output:

category
Balance    [1.0, 2.5, -0.5, -2.0, 8.0]
Card         [0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 3.5, 1.5]
Inquiry    [-5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0]
Name: vector, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work without using lists

```
def get_intent_centroid(array):
    centroid = np.zeros(len(array.iloc[0]))
    for vector in array:
        centroid = centroid + vector
    return centroid/len(array.iloc[0])

df.groupby('Catagory')['Vector'].apply(get_intent_centroid)
```